# How to use a macro inside \tl_set:Nx

Tags: programming, expl3

This code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \_text
\tl_set:Nn \text {1}
\tl_set:Nx \text {1{\text}}

\text
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

prints:

> 11

But when I try to use another macro inside `\tl_set:Nx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \_text
\tl_set:Nn \text {1}
\tl_set:Nx \text {1{\text}}

%this line breaks the compiler
\tl_set:Nx \text {\textcolor{red}{\text}}

\text
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Instead of printing '11' in red it gives this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@@mpstopdf@@unprotect ... \@@mpstopdf@@unprotect 
                                                   \unprotect \let \@@mpstopd... l.34     \def\unprotect
```

What's wrong?

Comment: By the way: Internal commands are getting two leading underscores: `\tl_new:N \__text`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to `x`-type expand (`\edef`) a LaTeX2e 'fragile' command (see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)). You should *never* use `\edef` on such a command. Instead, you have to use LaTeX2e's `\protected@edef`:

```
\protected@edef\text{\textcolor{red}{\text}}
```

The LaTeX2e kernel does not require e-TeX, so none of the core commands are e-TeX `\protected` from expansion. In LaTeX3 terms, `\textcolor` is not an expandable command.

Not directly relevant here, but I would not call a command `\text` as this is used by the AMS bundle (specifically `amstext`).

Comment: Do I need extra packages to run your code? It doesn't work. Prints: `You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.`

Comment: @user4035 As `\protected@edef` contains an `@`, you need to use `\makeatletter`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do for more on why!